# How i can a 1 Hz resolution fft, from a limited data (between 0 to 100 msec)?

Tags: fft

How i can have a 1 Hz resolution fft, from a limited data (between 0 to 100 msec)? 
sampling frequency is about 20 kHz or step time is 0.05 msec.
i try it by using zero padding but the resolution not satisfy me.

Comment: The answer is that you can't as shown by Marcus Muller's answer, if you have a reasonable SNR, you might get what you need with an parametric estimator like Burg, so I suggest accept Marcus's answer and repost without reference to the FFT.

Comment: I agree that you cannot do this. It would be helpful if you explained why you wanted to do it and why you think it should be possible. Otherwise, the answer is simply that you cannot do it which isn't very gratifying.

Answer (score 2):

Your DFT's resolution is **always** $\frac{f_\text{sample}}{L_\text{FFT}}$, by definition of what the DFT is.

So, for any given frequency resolution, you'd need to transform the inverse of that frequency worth in samples. So, for 1Hz resolution, you need 1/(1Hz) = 1s worth of samples; you're giving it less than 100ms, i.e. 1/10 of that – you can zero-pad, but for an FFT-based frequency estimate, that few samples simply won't be enough to give you a low-variance estimate.

So, garbage in, garbage out.